# Is there a way to identify Microsoft Office temporary files from their properties in OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, filesystems

When we open a Microsoft Office spreadsheet or document, generally a temporary file with the name starting with "~$" is created near the main file.

Is there any way to distinguish these files based on their properties (not their file name)?  Is there any property that distinguishes a temporary file in general?

I'm wanting to filter a directory listing by removing these temporary files, but need to do it without depending on the file names.

Comment: Here a thread on Office temporary files on Mac:[Locating Word AutoRecovery or Temporary Files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/locating-word-autorecovery-or-temporary-files/402bac20-654e-45fb-8283-57dbacb1795c).  Excel for Mac AutoRecovery : /Users/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Preferences/AutoRecovery

Comment: @HerbGu  Thanks, unfortunately the site is incorrect - these files are not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The only special property I can find about these files is that their attributes
are set as Hidden and Archived. Or at least this is the situation on Windows
(I don't know MacOS enough).

Although it is rare for Office files to have this combination of attributes,
checking for this combination is only a heuristic and not a sure thing.

The file name starting with "~$" is still the only sure indication.